# SAS Adjacency Matrix Creation

Tags: sas, social-networking, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix, sna

I have created this table:
[image: Table]

And from this I want to create an adjacency matrix which shows how many employee_id's the tables share. It would look like this (I think):
[image]
I'm not sure if I'm going about this the correct way. I think I may be doing it wrong. I know that this is probably easier if I have more SAS products but I only have the basic SAS enterprise guide to work with.

I really appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: How is the last column/row determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way using PROC CORR that's still better than the solution above. And you don't need to filter - it doesn't matter regarding the variables, you only specify them in the PROC CORR procedure.

```
data id;
input id:$4. human alien wizard;
cards;
1005 1 1 0
1018 0 0 1
1022 0 0 1
1024 1 0 0
1034 0 1 0
1069 0 1 0
1078 1 0 0
1247 1 1 1
;;;;
run;

ods output sscp=want;
proc corr  data=id  sscp ;
    var human alien wizard;
run;

proc print data=want;
    format _numeric_ 8.;
run;
```

Results are:

```
                   Obs    Variable       human       alien      wizard

                   1      human             4           2           1
                   2      alien             2           4           1
                   3      wizard            1           1           3
```

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't have known to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want but it does not give the thing you show as answer.

```
data id;
   input id:$4. human alien wizard;
   cards;
1005 1 1 0
1018 0 0 1
1022 0 0 1
1024 1 0 0
1034 0 1 0
1069 0 1 0
1078 1 0 0
1247 1 1 1
;;;;
   run;

proc corr noprint nocorr sscp out=sscp;
   var human alien wizard;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't include the last column/row. The ODS table is closer to the desired output, in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help. I can see there are many ways to do this now.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get the answer using this, although it does not include the last cell I wanted (human_alien_wizard):

```
proc transpose data=FULL_JOIN_ALL3 out=FULL_JOIN_ALL3_v2;
  by employee_id;
  var human_table alien_table wizard_table;
run; 

proc sql;
  create table FULL_JOIN_ALL3_v3 as
  select distinct a._name_ as anm,b._name_ as bnm,
  count(distinct case when a.col1=1 and b.col1=1 then a.employee_id else . end) as smalln
  from FULL_JOIN_ALL3_v2 a, FULL_JOIN_ALL3_v2 b
  where a.employee_id=b.employee_id
  group by anm,bnm
; 

proc tabulate data=FULL_JOIN_ALL3_v3;
 class anm bnm;
 var smalln;
 table anm='',bnm=''*smalln=''*sum=''*f=best3. / rts=5;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: You took the long way round.  You get the same thing directly from PROC CORR SSCP.

Comment: Using your method I still have to subset, but yes, your way is shorter. I just have to figure out if I were to create an automatic script, someone may still need to look at the data to subset on the correct rows and columns and it might be a different variable name each time so a macro variable would need to be created for that I believe. Here is the subset code.

Comment: `/*Proc CORR Method*/
proc corr data=FULL_JOIN_ALL3 noprint nocorr sscp out=sscp;
   run;
DATA Adjacency_Matrix (KEEP=Tables human_table alien_table wizard_table);
    SET sscp (rename=(_name_=Tables));
 If (Tables = 'Intercept' or Tables = 'employee_id') THEN DELETE;
    IF (_TYPE_ = 'SSCP') THEN OUTPUT;
 
RUN;
proc print data=Adjacency_Matrix;
   run;`

Comment: @hope288 If you add the variables to PROC CORR you're only filtering out the intercept and blanks. Notice that you still type out the vars once in your process (first_step) so it's no more automated that the other solution.